# Polymorphism with swiftui View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Every thing is in the title, is it possible to make some swiftui views in polymorphism, example :

```
protocol PQuestionView: View {
    associatedtype VM where VM : BaseQuestionViewModel
    var vm: Self.VM { get }
}
```

and make an array of that :

```
var quesitonViews:[PQuestionView] = []
```

without this error :

```
Protocol 'PQuestionView' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Comment: Instead of making an array of Views, in SwiftUI Views are a function of state, so that means that you should focus on your data (state) and render each element via a `ForEach`.  Use `@ViewBuilder` if you need to supply different types of views for each element.